# Is it faster in C if the If-Statement contains Assignment-Statements?

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages

I was reading the source code of lcc, in `alloc.c`:

```
if ((ap->next = freeblocks) != NULL) {
   freeblocks = freeblocks->next;
   ap = ap->next;
}
```

Why not

```
if (freeblocks != NULL) {
   ap->next = freeblocks;
   freeblocks = freeblocks->next;
   ap = ap->next;
}
```

Would the latter cause extra cost?

Comment: The identical code would be to do the assignment first, then the check. On the question (assuming fixed equivalent code): I am fairly sure this is just a style thing.

Comment: No, it's not faster. This is mainly a style choice.

Comment: You've written the code both ways.  Now **run it both ways** and soon you'll know which is faster.

Comment: @EricLippert haha you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance is a function of design in an optimizing compiler.

A number of years ago I reviewed a book manuscript for a publisher in which the author showed all kinds of programming tricks (like side effect assignments) that he claimed produced faster code.

I compiled his versions on several compilers and showed that none of his tricks produced faster code and most resulted in slower code.

You should always write the clearest code and let the compiler do the optimizing for you.

Assignments within if statements are a bad programming practice. Using = instead of == is a common error. Consistently avoiding side effect assignments makes these errors easier to spot.

Your mistake in translation shows how unclear the original code is.This kind of bad code often springs from assembly language programmers.

Your revised version translates literally into something like this (my pseudo assembly code)

```
MOV  freeblocks, next(R0)
TEST next(R0)                      ; Test for zero
JUMPNE TEST
```

While the literal translation of the original is more like:

```
MOV  freeblocks, next(R0)
JUMPNE TEST
```

Most systems test for zero as part of the move instruction. In theory, the original version is one instruction shorter.

However, any optimizing compiler will be smart enough to remove the redundant TEST.

Coding to outguess the compiler is a waste of time, effort, and clarity.

Answer (score 8):

The code snippets you post are not identical in function.

The first assigns `freeblocks` to `ap->next`, and if it is not `NULL`, proceeds with the other two statements.

The second, which you proposed, does not assign `freeblocks` to `ap->next` if freeblocks is `NULL`, and in fact does nothing in this case. This is not the same.

You could change your proposal to the following, which *is* functionally equivalent:

```
ap->next = freeblocks;
if (freeblocks != NULL) {
   freeblocks = freeblocks->next;
   ap = ap->next;
}
```

This avoids the assignment-as-part-of-a-condition which some would consider bad style. It is unlikely to cause any extra 'cost' assuming you mean execution speed or code size when compiled.

Comment: BTW: Explicit comparison to NULL is considered bad style in both C and C++, as it is superfluous.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I consider it good style, as it *captures the intent of the programmer more clearly*. Remember, *a small amount of redundancy is good* because it aids comprehension.

Comment: So, why not add another != 0 ? Or do you come from java?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I would argue that eliding the comparison is idiomatic C/C++, rather than being a best practice.  Whether it is preferable depends on your team.  Some people aren't fans of the fact that C/C++ allows one to use numbers and pointers (as opposed to explicit booleans) and prefer such comparisons (i.e., comparisons to 0/NULL) be made explicit.  On the other hand, some C/C++ programmers will look at you funny if you start talking about explicit booleans.

Comment: So, you are opposed to using idiomatic c/c++, because it does not honor a non-existing distinct boolean type? Yes, c gained (long after c++) a dedicated boolean type, but it still languishes after more than a decade, because it was never needed. Anyway, you need to understand and code for the c/c++ concept of truthiness anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you fixed your 2nd example to be functionally identical, say

```
ap->next = freeblocks;
if (freeblocks != NULL) {
    freeblocks = freblocks->next;
    ap = ap->next;
}
```

and as you're worried about speed, I'd expect you to have compiler optimzation on...

then the answer to your is-it-faster question would be: probably not.